# cannot resolve this error - NotSerializableException?

Tags: exception, tomcat, serializable

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException
```

Why am I getting this error while starting my server Tomcat 6.0?

```
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.janus.atreya.emr.service.LoginServiceImpl
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.janus.atreya.emr.service.LoginServiceImpl
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1029)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1475)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:643)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:438)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.janus.atreya.emr.service.LoginServiceImpl
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1000)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1551)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:994)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:523)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:469)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4774)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1290)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:323)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1086)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:450)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:615)
        ... 6 more
Nov 20, 2010 6:06:03 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager start
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.janus.atreya.emr.service.LoginServiceImpl
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1029)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1475)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:643)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:438)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.janus.atreya.emr.service.LoginServiceImpl
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1000)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1551)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:994)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:523)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:469)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4774)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1290)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:323)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1086)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:450)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:615)
        ... 6 more
Context Initialized
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true" reloadable="true" path="/janus-atreya-emr">
  <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" saveOnRestart="false"/>
</Context>
```

I can resolve this problem by changing this context file :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are using a class thatdoes not implement the serializable interface, but it should do at the exception point. have you any further informaton about the program?

Comment: I have updated my question, please note it. What do you mean by exception point?

Comment: i meant the point where the exception occurs :-) but you've just added it, as is see.